# How do I use both the --save-storage feature to save auth while using a custom setup?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

On [this page](https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#preserve-authenticated-state), Playwright recommends to use the --save-storage option with Codegen in order to save the auth state.
It also recommends just below to run a JS script instead of calling Codegen in CLI if we want to use a custom setup.
Now, I need to do both, i.e. save the auth state AND run a custom setup. But I can't find a way to do that in the documentation.